# Is there a specific graphic style or movement that inspired vintage (and some modern) euro-rave artwork?

Tags: typography, style-identification, style, posters, art

I'm working on a short film with trippy/vintage/lo-fi editing styles similar to those used in Travis Scott music videos, and it will use stylized intertitles as an artistic element.  However, instead of the heavy-metal/supernatural typographic/art direction of these videos (https://i.redd.it/86cv2i9wd31z.jpg https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/17/Travis_Scott_Watch.png), I want to have an art style similar to that of vintage euro-rave graphics and the aesthetic of a newer record label called ///AUTO.  This art style is stylistically similar to that of Travis Scott's but done without the grungy/edgy aesthetic of his style;  some elements I've noticed are gothic and kitsch fonts (sometimes condensed or with small kernings) with bold (almost brutalist) use of colour, as well as seemingly random and heavily edited photos used as backgrounds or complements to the text.  It seems to have influences from Swiss Style, but I feel like there's a more specific, better category to put this style in.  Does anyone know if a better category exists??

Examples:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I noticed there are close votes for needing more focus, yet a similar post of mine (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130692/is-there-a-name-for-the-general-style-of-designers-like-vignelli-mu%cc%88ller-brockm) was met with positive reception and was not closed.  Why are these votes here and how should I change the question?

Comment: It's possible that you simply got less close votes because of a combination of things, the main reason being your previous question hit HNQ and Twitter so it got way more upvotes. I don't think it should be closed, though I'm not sure if there's a specific name for this style.

Comment: @curious My last question hit twitter?  Do you have a link, because I had no idea

Comment: [Here it is](https://mobile.twitter.com/StackDesign/status/1189149981883731968)...we don't get any warning when stuff gets tweeted but we can see it in a post history.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's slightly off, some of this is a little like futurism of the 1990s and 2000s, the techno aesthetic. The [Y2K Aesthetic](https://twitter.com/y2k_aesthetic) feed is great for inspiration for fonts and color schemes of that time.